# Duplicated tag "wish"

Tags: support, tags, tag-wiki

Earlier today, neither the tag 'wish' nor 'tcl-wish' existed.  (I would use the square brackets, but I worry linking to them might wrongly convince some computer that both are legitimate unrelated tags.)

I submitted a question tagged 'wish'.  Since it was new, I added an excerpt for it.  SO informed me my tag edit would need to wait for review before anyone can see it.

Later on, I noticed that my question was retagged with 'tcl-wish'.  A decent tag renaming.  But also, it looks like my edit of 'wish' was accepted.  So now 'wish' has an excerpt and no questions, and 'tcl-wish' has a question and no excerpt, even though they really mean the same thing.

Do I have access to any tools that would let me delete the more ambiguous tag 'wish', or cause the two tags to be synonyms, or some other appropriate action?

If not, is there any additional action I should take to bring this situation to the attention of somebody who can fix it?  (Besides posting this question.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I changed the tag from [wish] to [tcl-wish] but didn't know there was a pending wiki edit. Now that your wiki excerpt has been accepted, I copied it to the [tcl-wish] wiki. Thanks for bringing that up.

Answer (score 1):

I think tags with very few quesions get auto deleted.   So just remove the "wish" tag from your question.

Comment: I had already removed the [wish] tag from the question, but that left a tag wiki for an unused tag and no wiki for the new tag. I fixed it.